# Custom keyboard shortcut to switch on certain language on Fedora

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I am using Fedora OS.
I need to set up the custom keyboard shortcut to switch keyboard to certain language. I. e. right Shift to English and left Shift to Russian.
Fedora keyboard settings allows only to set up shortcut for switching to "next language" or "previous language".
Peace!

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? (GNOME?) What Fedora release #? And, are you using the main Fedora OS, or the Russian Fedora Remix?

Comment: Hi Matt. Main Fedora 22, Gnone